# sudo apt install only from CD Rom

Tags: mount, apt

Somewhere in the corner of the hard drive I have the Debian iso sitting around and when I need to install something new I mount it with

```
sudo mount -o loop -t iso9660 /path/to/debian-10.3.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso /media/cdrom
```

Then I get on with my installation

```
sudo apt install something
```

Sometimes it pulls things from the cdrom, sometimes it pulls things from the internet. Can you do something to the install command which limits it only to the CDROM?

I just feel like having an older version sometimes and not using data unnecessarily.

Comment: A cdrom contains a very few percent of the available 40,000 packages, and no updates. Disabling the default mirror address´s : Synaptic → Settings → Repositories. ..... Or comment out the lines in `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: Thanks, I can see that that will work. Interesting, although it is a gigbyte big it is still only a few percent. Thing with that method however is you would have to change it back again after.